# How to show the weekly volume report in Professional Edition?

Tags: reporting, professional-edition

I'm creating the weekly volume report
e.g. Dec 4 to Dec 10
Dec 11 to Dec 17, how should I do that? The edition is Professional Edition.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more detail instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data for Grouping
The Fields pane displays fields from the selected report type, organized by folder. Before you group data in a summary report, drag at least a few fields into the preview pane.

Add a Grouping
Add a group by dropping a field onto a drop zone.

Report page showing where to drop a field into the drop zone to create a grouping
Click Show | Drop Zones to make them visible. You can also click a column menu for a field in the report and choose Group by this Field.

Link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_builder_fields_groupings.htm&type=5